# Add expires headers to nginx with uwsgi

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I have configure the nginx as reverse proxy with uwgsi now i want to add the expire headers on static content and added the following block in vhost configuration but this is not working.

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/mysite.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300;        
}

location ~* \.(jpg|svg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 1m;
}
```

what should i change to add expiry headers to static content?